# Access Foreign Key Field in Django

Tags: python, django

This is my `models.py` file:

```
class Appointment(models.Model):                  
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
    employees = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location

class Patient(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
    appointments = models.ForeignKey(Appointment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

In `views.py` I am trying to access the `first_name` of a `Patient` object, based on `Appointment`. So, for example, let's say that I have an appointment with a known `id`, and I want to get the `first_name` of the `patient` who has that appointment.

How would I do this in Django? I know only how to access a patient's appointment, but I can't figure out how to access an appointment's patient.

Comment: Isn't your relationship the wrong way round? It would make more sense for the foreign key to go from `Appointment` to `Patient` so that a patient can have more than one appointment?

Comment: Hi Iain. Yes, that would make more sense, but I am new to Django, and I was simply curious to know how to do the reverse operation in this case.

Answer (score 0):

According to your Model design a `Appointment` has many `Patient`. Basically what you can do to access a `Appointment's` `Patients` is add `_set` suffix on the reverse relation like following

```
appointment.patient_set.all()
```

See the first example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager).

Answer (score 0):

Filter patients with the known appointment id. Do something like this in your views.

```
appointment = get_object_or_404(Appointment, pk = appointment_id)   
patient = Patient.objects.filter(appointments=appointment)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
patient__first_name
```

for condition also you can use for example:

```
Q(patient__first_name__icontains='John')
```

note that `patient` is lowercase